# Asterisk Configuration on wireless network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asterisk, sip

I have installed Asterisk in my laptop on Ubuntu. Afterwards I created wireless network on the same machine (on which I have installed Asterisk). Next I installed 3CX softphone client on two laptops and connect these laptops to the network-established on Asterisk running laptop. But I am not able to connect my softphones with Asterisk (they are showing message "Server Unreachable"). Where am I going wrong? Should I use separate wireless router for connection?

Comment: what is the asterisk ip ? and the range of wireless network?

Comment: Misc. questions:
 - Are host-based firewalls running on any of the laptops?
 - Perform a netstat and check on what IP/interface Asterisk is listening.
 - If you're using hostnames (instead of IPs) are all three using the same DNS and are their hostnames in the DNS?
 - Is Asterisk configured to accept connections from the clients? Need to ensure that the server supports what the clients are attempting to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some cli ways to see if the client (3cx) is actually connecting and can probly give you some more info to figure out what is going on.

If there is communication at all you will see it with 
192.168.1.101 = your client ip(3cx)
sip set debug on
or
sip set debug ip 192.168.1.101

to turn the crazy messages off so you have time to review them. 
sip set debug off

if they are not detailed enough you could always do 
core set debug 9
and raise the info it pumps out but if you are getting nothing

Answer (score 0):

Are they (the server and the clients) on the same subnet ?
If not, is the link between the two subnets ROUTED or NAT ?

SIP (and the majority of lag-critical/media protocols) are known to not like NAT, because of UDP traffic, need for direct access to the IP and open ports,...
If this turns out to be the problem (e.g. if you've put a WIFI router  behind the broadband router), check if your WIFI router can do bridged mode. This is in most cases the cleanest way to solve these kind of problems. WIFI devices will be on the same subnet as cabled devices, WIFI devices will get IP from the DHCP service on the broadband router and from the same range as the cabled devices. It's also a solution if you need to connect from your smartphone to the television for example.